# Python Seaborn plot simple timeseries with pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Im trying to use seaborn's `tsplot` to plot my pandas dataframe with date on x-axis and number of clicks on y-axis. It is pretty simple plot.

This is my data:

```
"date","shown","clicked","converted","avg_cost_per_click","total_revenue","ad"
2015-10-01,65877,2339,43,0.9,641.62,"ad_group_1"
2015-10-02,65100,2498,38,0.94,756.37,"ad_group_1"
2015-10-03,70658,2313,49,0.86,970.9,"ad_group_1"
2015-10-04,69809,2833,51,1.01,907.39,"ad_group_1"
2015-10-05,68186,2696,41,1,879.45,"ad_group_1"
2015-10-06,66864,2617,46,0.98,746.48,"ad_group_1"
2015-10-07,68227,2390,42,0.94,462.33,"ad_group_1"
2015-10-08,68520,2909,46,1.07,441.28,"ad_group_1"
2015-10-09,67250,2385,49,0.88,602.14,"ad_group_1"
```

My code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv("ads.csv")
sb.tsplot(x=df.date,y=df.clicked,data=df)
```

i get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot label index with a null key
```

If seaborn is not good i dont mind trying other packages.
I tried matplotlib:

```
df.set_index(['date'],inplace=True) 
plt.figure()
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

but how do i select only certain y values to plot?

[image]
df.plot(df,index,df.converted) gave an error:

```
IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

Comment: If you are only looking to plot `date` v/s `clicked`, you could do : `df.plot(x='date', y='clicked', x_compat=True)`

Comment: I altered my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189368/pandas-plot-automatically-assigning-color-to-categories